# windowBackgrond

Tags: android, themes

Хочу добавить в приложение функцию смены темы. У меня несколько Activity и мне нужно, чтобы фон изменялся во всем приложении. Проблема: фон замечательно меняется через  - просто разный цвет, но я хочу чтобы в качестве фона выступала картинка. Насколько я понимаю (совсем недавно начал осваивать) это реализуется в style.xml через windowbackground>@drawable/имя_файла. Вес файла-картинки всего 300-450 кб, имя с маленькой буквы, разрешение 720*480. Перепробовал различные варианты - ничего не происходит.Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка.

Comment: Это в Андроиде? Укажите пожалуйста

Comment: Код? Где код? Как подсказать, в чем ошибка, если кода нет.

Answer (score 1):

В теме Theme.NoTitlteBar изменил как

```
<style name="Background" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

в manifest файле укажите

```
<application  android:theme="@style/Background"/>
```